# HTML5 Polygonic Selection onmousemove

Tags: html5-canvas

I need functionality like Photoshop polygon selection tool in HTML 5. I tried using HTML5 Path properties and I can draw line on canvas but can't have logic to make that line join and make polygon selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle clicks on the canvas and put the click coordinates in an array variable.

You can keep adding the points to path array until the path is complete. A path is complete when the user clicks on the first point after create 3 or more points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this application to draw your polygon and export it to give you the correct HTML and Javascript canvas statements to produce the polygon on a web page

[canvimation](http://canvimation.github.com/)